# Unexpected extraneous bytes after map value

Tags: java, cassandra, kundera

I have a table in cassandra which has a column of type MAP (i.e) **source_id_map map**

I am using kundera ORM for cassandra. During a **select**, I get the below exception

**Cassandra Version : 2.1.8**

Any ideas, what could be the possible cause ?

> Error while setting fieldsourceIdMap value via CQL, Caused by: .
>   org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: **Unexpected
>   extraneous bytes after map value**
>           at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MapSerializer.deserializeForNativeProtocol(MapSerializer.java:110)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.schemamanager.CassandraDataTranslator$MapTypeBuilder.decompose(CassandraDataTranslator.java:1177)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35836693/caused-by-javax-persistence-persistenceexception-org-apache-cassandra-serializ?noredirect=1#comment59383722_35836693

Comment: Coincidentally I only raised the other question as well. As per your recommendation, I added the below line to my persistence.xml as below, yet the error continues to reoccur. 

<property name="cql.version" value="3.0.0"></property>
<property name="default.validation.class" value="UTF8Type"></property>

Comment: Did you create the table and  add the data with CQL3 enabled as well ? If not , please do the same