# Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: Unexpected extraneous bytes after map value

Tags: java, cassandra, kundera

I have a table in cassandra which has a column of type MAP (i.e) source_id_map map

When I try to read a row from this table, I see that there is some issue while reading column of map type as below

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: Unexpected
>   extraneous bytes after map value
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.setCollectionValue(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:2526)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.setFieldValueViaCQL(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:1504)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.populateViaThrift(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:1163)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.onColumn(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:1054)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.populateEntity(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:653)

Another exception that I notice is as below.

> Error while retrieving fieldUTF8Type value via CQL, Caused by: .
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>           at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:267)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytes(ByteBufferUtil.java:543)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytesWithShortLength(ByteBufferUtil.java:552)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.CollectionSerializer.readValue(CollectionSerializer.java:128)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MapSerializer.deserializeForNativeProtocol(MapSerializer.java:104)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.schemamanager.CassandraDataTranslator$MapTypeBuilder.decompose(CassandraDataTranslator.java:1177)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.schemamanager.CassandraDataTranslator$MapTypeBuilder.access$4800(CassandraDataTranslator.java:1100)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.schemamanager.CassandraDataTranslator.decompose(CassandraDataTranslator.java:507)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.setCollectionValue(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:2518)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.setFieldValueViaCQL(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:1504)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.populateViaThrift(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:1163)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.onColumn(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:1054)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.datahandler.CassandraDataHandlerBase.populateEntity(CassandraDataHandlerBase.java:653)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase$CQLClient.executeQuery(CassandraClientBase.java:2272)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase.executeSelectQuery(CassandraClientBase.java:926)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClient.executeQuery(ThriftClient.java:1062)
>           at com.impetus.client.cassandra.query.CassQuery.populateEntities(CassQuery.java:153)
>           at com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryImpl.fetch(QueryImpl.java:1377)
>           at com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:200)

Comment: Please make sure that cql3 is enabled while querying as well as inserting data using EntityManager.

Comment: @ChhaviGangwal I am new to cassandra as well as kundera. Can you please let me know how to ensure cqls3 is enabled ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enable CQL3 both while inserting as well as reading data

```
Map propertyMap = new HashMap();
propertyMap.put(CassandraConstants.CQL_VERSION, CassandraConstants.CQL_VERSION_3_0);
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cassandra-pu",propertyMap);
```